# How can i work this code as in the given demo link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var sum = parseInt($('select[name="bathrooms"]').val() * 25) + parseInt($('select[name="bedrooms"]').val() * 8);
  $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <label>Bedrooms</label>
  <select class="form-control bedrooms-count" name="bedrooms" id="booking-field-bedrooms">
  <option value="0"  >0</option>
  <option value="1"  selected>1</option>
  <option value="2"  >2</option>
  <option value="3"  >3</option>
  <option value="4"  >4</option>
  <option value="5"  >5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <label>Bathrooms</label>
  <select id="booking-field-bathrooms" class="form-control bathrooms-count" name="bathrooms">
<option value="0" >0</option>
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="4" >4</option>
<option value="5" >5</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5 set-frequency-wrapper">
  <label>Set Frequency</label>
  <select class="form-control booking-field-frequency" name="method" id="booking-field-frequency">
<option value="mini" selected="selected">MINI DELUXE</option>
<option value="deluxe">DELUXE(SPRING CLEAN)</option>
<option value="bond">BOND CLEANING</option>
</select>
</div>

<!--add-booking-step-1 closed-->
<div class="add-booking-step-2">
  <h3 class="section-title-info">Extras</h3>
  <div class="service-listing oven-in-service">
    <label id="term-1">
<input id="term-1" name="oveninservice" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="60"/>
Oven in Service
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing oven-only">
    <label>
<input id="term-2" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="2"/>
Oven Only
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing windows-int-ext">
    <label>
<input id="term-3" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="3"/>
Windows Int/Ext
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing kitchen">
    <label>
<input id="term-4" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="4"/>
Kitchen
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing walls">
    <label>
<input id="term-5" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="5"/>
Walls
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing rangehood">
    <label>
<input id="term-6" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="6"/>
Rangehood
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing sweep-garage">
    <label>
<input id="term-7" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="7"/>
Sweep Garage
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing fans">
    <label>
<input id="term-8" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="8" />
Fans
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing lights">
    <label>
<input id="term-9" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="9" />
Lights
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing toilets">
    <label>
<input id="term-10" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="10" />
Toilets
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing mirrors">
    <label>
<input id="term-11" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="11" />
Mirrors
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing lounge">
    <label>
<input id="term-12" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="12" />
Lounge
</label>
  </div>
  <div id='sum'></div>
```

PRICE LIST

```
Bathroom                              $ 25  
Bedroom                               $ 8  
Oven in Service                       $ 60  
Oven Only                             $ 80       
Windows Int/Ext                       $ 7.5  
Kitchen                               $ 20  
Walls                                 $ 5  
Rangehood                             $ 17.5  
Sweep Garage                          $ 7.5  
Fans                                  $ 5  
Lights                                $ 3.5  
Toilets                               $ 12.5  
Mirrors                               $ 3.5  
Lounge                                $ 7.5
```

I need to configure the amount like this.

Demo Link - https://www.kingofmaids.com/book-in-30-secs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the values correctly:

```
var sum =  parseInt($('select[name="bathrooms"]').val(), 10)*25 +
           parseInt($('select[name="bedrooms"]').val(), 10)*8;
// for checkbox values addition to the sum
sum += parseInt($(':checkbox:checked').val(), 10) || 0; // add checked value or 0
```

```js
$('select, :checkbox').change(function() {
  var sum = parseInt($('select[name="bathrooms"]').val(), 10) * 25 + parseInt($('select[name="bedrooms"]').val(), 10) * 8 || 0;
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
  });
  $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <label>Bedrooms</label>
  <select class="form-control bedrooms-count" name="bedrooms" id="booking-field-bedrooms">
  <option value="0"  >0</option>
  <option value="1"  selected>1</option>
  <option value="2"  >2</option>
  <option value="3"  >3</option>
  <option value="4"  >4</option>
  <option value="5"  >5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <label>Bathrooms</label>
  <select id="booking-field-bathrooms" class="form-control bathrooms-count" name="bathrooms">
<option value="0" >0</option>
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="4" >4</option>
<option value="5" >5</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5 set-frequency-wrapper">
  <label>Set Frequency</label>
  <select class="form-control booking-field-frequency" name="method" id="booking-field-frequency">
<option value="mini" selected="selected">MINI DELUXE</option>
<option value="deluxe">DELUXE(SPRING CLEAN)</option>
<option value="bond">BOND CLEANING</option>
</select>
</div>

<!--add-booking-step-1 closed-->
<div class="add-booking-step-2">
  <h3 class="section-title-info">Extras</h3>
  <div class="service-listing oven-in-service">
    <label id="term-1">
<input id="term-1" name="oveninservice" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="60"/>
Oven in Service
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing oven-only">
    <label>
<input id="term-2" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="2"/>
Oven Only
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing windows-int-ext">
    <label>
<input id="term-3" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="3"/>
Windows Int/Ext
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing kitchen">
    <label>
<input id="term-4" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="4"/>
Kitchen
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing walls">
    <label>
<input id="term-5" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="5"/>
Walls
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing rangehood">
    <label>
<input id="term-6" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="6"/>
Rangehood
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing sweep-garage">
    <label>
<input id="term-7" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="7"/>
Sweep Garage
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing fans">
    <label>
<input id="term-8" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="8" />
Fans
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing lights">
    <label>
<input id="term-9" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="9" />
Lights
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing toilets">
    <label>
<input id="term-10" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="10" />
Toilets
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing mirrors">
    <label>
<input id="term-11" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="11" />
Mirrors
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="service-listing lounge">
    <label>
<input id="term-12" type="checkbox" class="clean-addons" value="12" />
Lounge
</label>
  </div>
  <div id='sum'></div>
```

Comment: Working of checkbox is ok,but how can i add the value of checked checkbox to the total.

Comment: `sum += parseInt($(':checkbox:checked').val(), 10) || 0;` do this way.

Comment: Its not working,can you please add this code in snippet or comment the full code.

Comment: @Ridhik check the snippet added.